# How to execute a script just before end of execution duration / iteration specified for a thread group in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute logout script just before my execution duration end ( when executing my script in duration mode ) and after iteration loop end ( when executing my script in iteration mode ).

Comment: add logout sampler after iteration isn't working? adding a tearDown Thread Group which will be execute right after your code is ok?

Comment: Logout cannot be added to Teardown thread group since Logout request is required for only one Thread group of my test plan.